# add the values according to appending the values

Tags: ios

How to add the values according to appending the values in swift3.

this is my datasource:-

```
 class QM_ChartDataSourceModel: NSObject {
    var dataListArray:Array<QM_CartModel>? = []


    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()
        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil{

            newArray = self.getJsonDataStored22()
        }
        else{
            newArray = array!

        }

        var datalist:Array<QM_CartModel> = []
        for dict in newArray{

            let model = QM_CartModel(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
    }
}

typealias dummyDataSource22 =  QM_ChartDataSourceModel
extension dummyDataSource22{

    func getJsonDataStored22() ->Array<Dictionary<String,String>>{

        let jsonArray = [["id":"311","name":"Dosa Fest","price":"QR 40","quantity":"3"],["id":"312","name":"Organic Vegan Fest","price":"QR 40","quantity":"2"],["id":"313","name":"Food Of Life Time","price":"QR 56","quantity":"7"],["id":"314","name":"Tea Time","price":"QR 88","quantity":"1"],["id":"315","name":"Dosa Fest","price":"QR 13","quantity":"6"],["id":"316","name":"Organic Vegan Fest","price":"QR 4","quantity":"8"],["id":"317","name":"Food Of Life Time","price":"QR 90","quantity":"3"],["id":"318","name":"Tea Time","price":"QR 66","quantity":"2"],["id":"319","name":"Dosa Fest","price":"QR 81","quantity":"6"],["id":"320","name":"Organic Vegan Fest","price":"QR 49","quantity":"2"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

        return jsonArray
    }






}
```

in tableviewcell:

```
 func setEventData(carts:QM_CartModel)
    {
        self.name.text = carts.cartname
        self.price.text = carts.cartsum
        self.itemQuantityStepper.value = 1
        setItemQuantity(quantity)

        print(self.price.text)


        let value = carts.cartsum



        let x: Int? = Int(value!)
        print(x)


        let add = x! 
        print(add)


        let theIntegerValue1 :Int =  add
        let theStringValue1 :String = String(theIntegerValue1)
        self.price.text = theStringValue1


    }
```

my model:-

```
class QM_CartModel: NSObject {

    var cartname :String!
    var cartprice:String!
    var cartquantity:String!
    var carttotalprice:String!
    var carttotal:String!
    var cartQR:String!
    var cartvalue:String!
    var cartsum:String?
    var cartid:String!



     init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

                guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String else {
                    return
                }



                if     let quantity = dictionary["quantity"] as? String{


                    let price = dictionary["price"] as? String
                    let id = dictionary["id"] as? String
                    self.cartid = id
                    self.cartprice = price

                    self.cartquantity = quantity

                    let fullNameArr = price?.components(separatedBy: " ")

                    let QR    = fullNameArr?[0]
                    let value = fullNameArr?[1]

                    self.cartQR = QR
                    self.cartvalue = value

                    let x: Int? = Int(value!)
                    print(x)

                    let y:Int? = Int(quantity)
                    print(y)

                    let sum = x! * y!
                     print(sum)

                    let  sum1 = String(describing: sum)
                    cartsum = sum1








        }
```

my viewmodel:-

```
class QM_ChartViewModel: NSObject {


    var datasourceModel:QM_ChartDataSourceModel


    var insertedArray:QM_CartModel? 

    var filteredListArray:Array<QM_CartModel>? = []


     var totalListArray:Array<QM_CartModel>? = []

    init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel: QM_ChartDataSourceModel) {
        datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
        print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)

    }


    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> QM_CartModel{
        return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]

    }

    func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {

        return datasourceModel.dataListArray!.count
    }

    func delete(atIndex indexPath: IndexPath) {

        datasourceModel.dataListArray!.remove(at: indexPath.row)

    }

    func search(idsearch :String?) {

        filteredListArray = datasourceModel.dataListArray?.filter{($0.cartid?.range(of: idsearch!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil)}
        print(filteredListArray)


    }

    func searchindex(objectatindex index: Int) ->  QM_CartModel {

        return self.filteredListArray![index]

    }


    func total()
    {        totalListArray = datasourceModel.dataListArray?.filter{($0.cartsum != nil)}
        print(totalListArray)


    }


    func add(){

            datasourceModel.dataListArray?.append(insertedArray!)
            print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)
            print(insertedArray?.offerAddName)
            print(insertedArray?.offerprice)

            self.datasourceModel.dataListArray = datasourceModel.dataListArray

            print(insertedArray?.cartsum)


    }


    func addquantity(quantity:Int)
    {
       // datasourceModel.dataListArray?.filter{ $0.cartid! == cartaddedid! }.first?.qty = quantity as NSNumber?


    }


 }
```

in viewcontroller my code as below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return chartViewModel.numberOfRowsInSection(section: section)

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let identifier = "cell"
        var cell: QM_ChartCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? QM_ChartCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "QM_ChartCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? QM_ChartCell
        }


        cell.setEventData(carts: chartViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))
        print(cell.numbers)
```

[see here can see the total.So that way i need to display the total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOCbn.png)

this is my code ...here i getting the values model.cartsum.So this value is appending in   `var number:[String] = []`

.But here i need-as values are appending ,here i need to add the number.So first value is 1 and second value is 2 then i need to add this values.And if next number is 3 then i need to get sum = 6.
How to get

Comment: You will need to convert the strings to integers or floats or something, but you can't do in it `cellForRowAt`. This function will be called many times.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes i understood this function is calling many times.But i need only according to the count .How to do

Comment: You would need to calculate the total in some other function, but why do you have an array of strings if you want a total?

Comment: @Paulw11 can u show how to do ..i just to add the cartsum which is getting from model.I am doing in mvvm

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do, but you can use `Int(someString)` to get an *optional Int* that you would need to unwrap

Comment: @Paulw11 please check.I have updated my code.  as i get self.price.text at each indexpath of tableview ,but i need to add this price and need to display the total price.How to do

Comment: Do you want to display a "running total" in your tableview?  I would advise against storing your prices as "QR 40"in your data model.  Your price should be stored as an Int or Float. Any required currency symbol should be added during output. Otherwise, you will need to extract the digits from the string before you convert them to an Int

Comment: @Paulw11 please check ,i have updated ..In that i already -cartsum gets only int value. i need to display the total in the label.Not in tableview.total of all price not single price.How to find the total here?

Comment: Ok, but I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve by adding numbers in `cellForRowAt`. Why is `cartSum` a `String`?  Why do you use `String(describing:)` to create the string?

Comment: @Paulw11 i thought i firstly append the numbers in array then find the total,that is why i used numbers adding.

Comment: But `cellForRowAt` will be called in random order and may be called multiple times For the same row. You can't do any calculation there anyway.  You should simply loop over your array after you have loaded the JSON and calculate the total.

Comment: @Paulw11 i have not used the api.I have used dummy data.CAN u show how to do

Comment: Could you please show the screenshot or any example what you actually want? Your question is not clear enough for me.

Comment: @TheTiger i have upload an example(Screenshot) please check,I need according...

Comment: @abel You want to calculate that `$435.60` for all cart data?

Comment: @TheTiger As cart data display i need to calculate the total

Comment: @TheTiger how to find the total

Comment: @abel Please check my answer.

Comment: how to solve the problem

Comment: @abel Please take a breath and read my comment then look into my answer. I have already answered for your question.

Comment: @abel Have your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate all the cart stuff just after you get it either from service or from local. You don't need to do calculation in `cellForRowAtIndex:` method because it should be done once.

I assume this is your data structure as mentioned in question.

```
let jsonArray = [["id":"311","name":"Dosa Fest","price":"QR 40","quantity":"3"],
                     ["id":"312","name":"Organic Vegan Fest","price":"QR 40","quantity":"2"],
                     ["id":"313","name":"Food Of Life Time","price":"QR 56","quantity":"7"],
                     ["id":"314","name":"Tea Time","price":"QR 88","quantity":"1"],
                     ["id":"315","name":"Dosa Fest","price":"QR 13","quantity":"6"],
                     ["id":"316","name":"Organic Vegan Fest","price":"QR 4","quantity":"8"],
                     ["id":"317","name":"Food Of Life Time","price":"QR 90","quantity":"3"],
                     ["id":"318","name":"Tea Time","price":"QR 66","quantity":"2"],
                     ["id":"319","name":"Dosa Fest","price":"QR 81","quantity":"6"],
                     ["id":"320","name":"Organic Vegan Fest","price":"QR 49","quantity":"2"]]
```

**Here is how to calculate the total of the cart. As per your data considering price is in `Int`**

```
var total = 0
for item in jsonArray {

    /// Will check if quantity is available in dictionary and convertible into an Int else will be 0
    let quantity = Int(item["quantity"] ?? "0") ?? 0

    /// Will check price key exists in the dictionary
    if let priceStr = item["price"] {

        /// Will fetch the last components and check if it is convertible into an Int else 0
        let price =  Int(priceStr.components(separatedBy: " ").last ?? "0") ?? 0
        /// Multiply price with quantity and add into total
        total += price * quantity
    }
}

print(total)
```

> **Output:** 1776

**Another way:**

```
let total = jsonArray.map { (item) -> Int in
        let quantity = Int(item["quantity"] ?? "0") ?? 0
        let price = Int(item["price"]?.components(separatedBy: " ").last ?? "0") ?? 0
        return quantity * price
    }.reduce(0, +)

print(total)
```

Comment: i have updated my full code.please check.As u given the code,where this code should apply,and what changes should do

Comment: In your `ViewModel` in `init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel: QM_ChartDataSourceModel)` constructor you can calculate the cart total by looping `datasourceModel.dataListArray`.

Comment: i need according:- as i uploaded the screenshot here can see For each product it has its own price .I need the total price of added product.Not each product total.That is already i finded.Here i need the total of all.That means in screen shot can see Total= $435.60.I need that total.

Comment: @abel Which is your cart array? As per your code you are using `datasourceModel.dataListArray` as your table data source. And if this is the array then it is calculating correct total as required.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code if you have array of `Int`

```
var arrayOfInt = [2,3,4,5,4,7,2]
let reducedNumberSum = arrayOfInt.reduce(0,+)
print(reducedNumberSum)
```

> Answer: 27

In your code

```
let model = chartViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
```

Please describe more so we can answer according your problem.

Comment: Thanks @the tiger